# IBM Tivoli Network Manager IP Edition - Job does not run

Tags: networking

Since our network discovery takes too long I tried to split the biggest job into two parts. The two parts use the same Perl script but have a different scope.

I copied a Job (Agent) doing the following:

- Copied the .agnt file
- Copied the associated perl script

The problem is that one or the other job (changes randomly) does not run. The Disco Process will fail eventually.

In the log of the job which does not run I see the following error message:

> Wed Jul 18 08:48:54 2012  Warning: Failed to send on transport layer found in file CRivObjSockClient.cc at line 1293 - Client My_MacTable_Cis is not connected to service Helper

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to change the Agent name in the Perl-Script.
The original Agent was called My_MacTable_Cis. The new Agent name is My_MacTable_Cis2
So I had to update it in the perl-script. This fixed the problem:

```
my $myAgent = new MyAgent(
    agent => $agent,
    tableName => $m_tablename,
    agentName => "My_MacTable_Cis2" ...
)

my $TestNE=new RIV::Record($data);
$TestNE->{'m_UpdAgent'}="My_MacTable_Cis2";

$agent=new RIV::Agent($param, "My_MacTable_Cis2");
```

**Update**

In case the Perlscript is fine then the following might help:

- remove / register your agents
- itnm_stop
- restart the operating system
- itnm_start